# How to store the result of the expression into a variable in Windows batch script?

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I have the windows batch script that replaces `\` by `_`.

I want to know what is needed to store the result of the replace expression into a variable?

Below is the script I have.

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (E:\Windows_Scripts\server.txt) DO (
    Set "servername=%%x" 
    Set "Pattern=\" 
    Set "Replace=_" 

    call echo %%servername:%Pattern%=%Replace%%%
)
```

I want to store the result of the below expression

```
%%servername:%Pattern%=%Replace%%%
```

into a variable. How can this be done?

Comment: The `SET` command is used to assign a value to a variable.

Comment: Assuming the file server.txt contains more than one line, storing to a single variable would overwrite the content with each iteration - so only the last entry persists.

Comment: Yes. Consider, if the file contains SERVER1, SERVER2, SERVER3\MICROSOFT, then output obtained as SERVER1, SERVER2, SERVER3_MICROSOFT. I need to store these output into a variable for each iteration.

Comment: So all the server names are on a single line separated by commas?

Comment: You should first take `Set "Pattern=\" ` and `Set "Replace=_"`  out of the loop and place them before the `FOR` command. You will get wrong results at best, and most probably syntax error if  the `Pattern` variable is not defined before the loop.

Comment: Sorry, it is not in a single line. Each server names are in a seperate line like below
SERVER1
SERVER2
SERVER3\MICROSOFT.

Comment: And by running the above script, i'm not getting any error. The above script works for me. The thing is i need to store the value obtained from the expression (%%servername:%Pattern%=%Replace%%%) into variable. The output obtained is "SERVER3_MICROSOFT". This i need to store into variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the variable at each iteration with the delayed expansion activated!!

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=\"
Set "Replace=_"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%x in (server.txt) DO (
  Set "servername=%%x"
  Set "$output=!servername:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
  echo !$output!
)
```